# How to use Custom log handler to set maximum backup logs of all time for wildfly jboss

Tags: logging, jboss, wildfly, backup, customization

I got an limitation in PeriodicSizeRotatingFileHandler of jboss. It rotates logs backup on daily basis an creates let's 20 backup index for one day. Next day it creates new 20 backups and doesn't delete older. Again next to next day same 20 backups. This consumes a ot of memory that we are not deleting older days file.

I use custom-handler and create a new class extending PeriodicSizeRotatingFileHandler. which has the new field maxBackupAllTime. you can set a value for it and it works to delete files older than this index.

Here is an example of how you can create a custom handler to do this. All custom handlers must extend java.util.logging.Handler. For this example I am extending org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicSizeRotatingFileHandler as it would help me leverage some of the features PeriodicSizeRotatingFileHandler provides.

```
public class PeriodicSizeRotatingCustomFileHandler extends PeriodicSizeRotatingFileHandler {

    private int maxBackupAllTime = 5;

    public int getMaxBackupAllTime() {
        return maxBackupAllTime;
    }

    public void setMaxBackupAllTime(int maxBackupAllTime) {
        checkAccess(this);
        synchronized (outputLock) {
            this.maxBackupAllTime = maxBackupAllTime;
        }
    }

    public PeriodicSizeRotatingCustomFileHandler() {
        super();
    }

    public PeriodicSizeRotatingCustomFileHandler(final String fileName, final boolean append)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        super(fileName, append);
    }

    /**
     * @param maxBackupAllTime
     */
    public PeriodicSizeRotatingCustomFileHandler(final String maxBackupAllTime) {
        super();
        this.maxBackupAllTime = Integer.parseInt(maxBackupAllTime);
    }

    /**
     * @param fileName
     * @param suffix
     * @param rotateSize
     * @param maxBackupIndex
     * @param append
     * @param maxBackupAllTime
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     */
    public PeriodicSizeRotatingCustomFileHandler(final String fileName, final String suffix, final String rotateSize,
            final String maxBackupIndex, final String append, final String maxBackupAllTime)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        super(fileName == null ? null : new File(fileName), suffix, Boolean.parseBoolean(append));
        this.setFile(fileName == null ? null : new File(fileName));
        this.setRotateSize(Long.parseLong(rotateSize));
        this.setMaxBackupIndex(Integer.parseInt(maxBackupIndex));
        setMaxBackupAllTime(Integer.parseInt(maxBackupAllTime));

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicSizeRotatingFileHandler#preWrite(org.jboss.logmanager.ExtLogRecord)
     * After Super class preWrite() execution, we check total logs file count, should not be more than @maxBackupAllTime
     */
    @Override
    public void preWrite(final ExtLogRecord record) {
        super.preWrite(record);
        if (maxBackupAllTime != 0) {
            File logfile = getFile();
            File path = new File(logfile.getParent());
            List<File> logFilesInDirectory = Arrays.asList(path.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

                public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                    boolean result;
                    if (name.startsWith("server.log")) {
                        result = true;
                    } else {
                        result = false;
                    }
                    return result;
                }
            }));

            if (logFilesInDirectory.size() > this.maxBackupAllTime) {
                logFilesInDirectory.sort(Comparator.comparing(File::lastModified));
                int filesCountToRemove = logFilesInDirectory.size() - this.maxBackupAllTime - 1;
                List<File> filesToRemove = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < filesCountToRemove; i++) {
                    filesToRemove.add(logFilesInDirectory.get(i));
                }
                try {
                    deleteSelectedFiles(filesToRemove);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    reportError("Unable to delete log file", e, ErrorManager.OPEN_FAILURE);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes the specified files.
     *
     * @param path
     *            the file to delete
     * @throws IOException
     *             if a problem occurred deleting the file
     */
    private void deleteSelectedFiles(final List<File> selectedForDeletion) throws IOException {
        for (final File file : selectedForDeletion) {
            Files.deleteIfExists(file.toPath());
        }
    }
```

Here in this custom handler we would be overriding preWrite() method to check if the files' count exceeds than number given in maxBackupAllTIme and delete extra backup files.

Once custom handler is created we will have to package the class into a JAR file (e.g custom-logger.jar) and create a JBoss module. Module.xml would look like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module name="org.jboss.logmanager.custom.handlers" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.6">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="custom-logger.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- for java.beans -->
        <module name="java.desktop"/>
        <module name="java.logging"/>
        <module name="java.xml"/>
        <module name="javax.json.api"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.modules" export="true"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" export="true"/>
        <module name="org.wildfly.common" export="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

You can create  the module using JBoss CLI or you can create it manually by JAR and module.xml at correct location.
Or you can manually create the directory org/jboss/logmanager/custom/handlers/main and copy both the jar files and module.xml in it.

Once module is created successfully, we will have to configure custom handler under logging subsystem of your configuration like in domain.xml. Configuration XML would look like:

```
<custom-handler name="FILEA" 
class="org.jboss.logmanager.custom.handlers.PeriodicSizeRotatingCustomFileHandler" 
module="org.jboss.logmanager.custom.handlers">
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
        <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
        </formatter>
        <properties>
                <property name="fileName" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/server.log"/>
                <property name="suffix" value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <property name="rotateSize" value="1000000"/>
                <property name="maxBackupIndex" value="5"/>
                <property name="append" value="false"/>
                <property name="maxBackupAllTime" value="8"/>
        </properties>
</custom-handler>

<root-logger>
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
        <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILEA"/>
        </handlers>
</root-logger>
```

This is just an example of how you can use custom handlers in JBoss logmanager to filter exception logs. You can explore other ways for achieving the results.

Comment: Is there a question here?